# Node js query for array items in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am new in node js and I need a query for my node js script, so that it return query item from my MongoDB.
What I am doing, I applying a query using node js for particular questionId which score is 1 inside MongoDB data are stored in array form,
so that query will return only score's 1 questionId not score's 0.

```
{
"_id": "57cfc7b86f0e51ee17d4c512",
"question": [
        {
        "questionId": "57ce608e2a0d6cad8c48ef8f",
        "score": 1,
        },
        {
        "questionId": "57ce608e2a0d6cad8c48ef90",
        "score": 0,
        },
        {
        "questionId": "57ce608e2a0d6cad8c48ef91",
        "score": 0,
        }
]
}
```

The node js code query that i applying is 
I have tried two queries but they return all array items
    query = {'question.score':1};
    query = {'question':{$eq:{'score':1}}};

```
function(){
             var query = {'question.score':1};
              childQuizInfo.findOne(query,function(err,data){
                        if(err) return next(err);
                        res.send(data);
                      });
                    }
```

I am using this query so that it return response only "questionId":"57ce608e2a0d6cad8c48ef8f", but it return all items of array.

Comment: As the array *question* is a field of the document, you will always get back all the content. You could not achieve this with a plain query, instead try tu use an *agregation*  [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Comment: You can try the answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection).

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation pipeline:

```
childQuizInfo.aggregate([{ $unwind: "$question" }, { $match: { "question.score": 1 } }, { $project: { "_id": 0, "questionId": "$question.questionId" } } ]);
```

Useful link:

http://excellencenodejsblog.com/mongoose-aggregation-count-group-match-project/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([{$unwind:"$question"},{$match:{"question.score":1}}]);
```